# ¿Cómo presionar ENTER?

Tags: c++, winapi

Buenas noches para todos, tengo un inconveniente con un código para presionar enter. El código cumple su función, en el escritorio o en un bloc de notas pero dentro de un juego Adobe Flash en Google Chrome  no lo hace ¿cuál sería la modificación que necesita?

```
void pressEnter();
            {
                INPUT ip;
                ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                ip.ki.time = 0;
                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
                ip.ki.wScan = VK_RETURN; //VK_RETURN is the code of Return key
                ip.ki.wVk = 0;
                ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));


            }
```

Pude solucionarlo y lo dejo aquí para que otra persona lo pueda utilizar:

```
                INPUT inp[2] = { 0 };
                inp[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                inp[0].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
                inp[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                inp[1].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
                inp[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

                SendInput(2, inp, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: Hola PVP_Venezuela, sería mejor si colocas la solución en una respuesta ;)

Comment: Gracias, que amable;)